# c# output from a form to another class

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance

Hi I am creating a application of three types of dark chocolate.
I have a windows form (inherited from another form) and one other class.

For my windows form class:

```
    darkchoco darkco = new darkchoco();
    string[] darkType = new string[3] { "Dark Chocolate Truffle", "Dark Chocolate Bar", "Dark Chocolate Almond" };
    public string returnType;
```

darkco is the another class.
for the box in the windows form, I have a mousedown action defined:

```
    private void optionBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        optionBox1.DoDragDrop(optionBox1.Text,
            DragDropEffects.Copy);
        returnType = darkType[0];
        darkco.darkType = returnType;
```

for my darkco class, I have:

```
         public string darkType;
         public override string ToString()
    {
        return "For dark chocolate, you have selected: " + darkType;
    }
```

I don't know why the darkType doesn't show up, the only thing shows us is "for dark chocolate, you have selected: " then nothing. My question is where is my code wrong that makes darkType not showing up.

Looking forward to get it fixed, thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the data from `darkchoco` when you want the returned string? If you're using `darkchoco darkco = new darkchoco()` then you're creating a new instance of the class and your `darkType` variable will be null. Try making `darkchoco` into a `public static class darkchoco` and accessing it via `darkchoco.MethodToReturnString()` and see if it works.

Comment: Try and place a debugger in your optionBox1_MouseDown method at -  darkco.darkType = returnType;. See what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not complete. How do you transfer the chocolate type to your darktype class? I'm not sure your darktype variable is part of the darktype class. I would expect something like this. Now you can construct your darco class, using the chocolate type as construction parameter. You also can add logic to the property.

```
    public class darco
    {
    public string darktype { set; get; } = String.Empty;

    public darco( string mydarktype)
        {
        darktype = mydarktype;
        }

    public override string ToString()
        {
        return "For dark chocolate, you have selected: " + darkType;
        }

    }
```